# Does the ECS task definition correctly load variables from the parameter store that have a colon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-parameter-store

Does the ECS task definition correctly load variables from the parameter store that have a colon? Because when the value of a variable is entered manually everything works, but when it is taken from the parameter store it has the value of an empty string.

Comment: How about showing your task definition? How about testing with a parameter store value that doesn't have a colon, to narrow down the issue?

Comment: Ok, problem solved. The task definition correctly reads variables with a colon :) The problem was with an external library that couldn't parse the variable https:endpoint.com:<port>, but after adding a '/' at the end it worked.